# To Hide and show the image depends on the value of seekbar

Tags: android, seekbar

`SeekBar` value starts from 0 to 100 %. I want to show the image depends on the seekbar percentage. if `seekbar` reaching 10 % , i want to show 10 % length of the image. If seekbar reaching 50 % , i want to show half of image. Likewise i want to show the image depends on `seekbar` value. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a Layout as container with orientation="horizontal", put your image inside and put also a void ImageView. Then adjust the weight of your image and the void image so you can replaicate the seekbar percentage.

The xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewYourImage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:src="..." />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewVoidImage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and the code:

```
int percentage = 10;
int max = 100;

imageViewVoidImage.setLayoutParams(
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int) (max * 10f - percentage * 10f)));
imageViewYourImage.setLayoutParams(
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int) (percentage * 10f)));
```

Comment: @Seraphim sir can we set the value of imageview on seekbar onStartTrackingTouch and onstopping touch ....